# Do Users Get Credit Toward "Edit and Answer" Badges for Edits That are Rolled Back

Tags: support, tags, edits, badges, rollbacks

One of my questions was edited just to add a tag by a user that gave a reasonable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35893826/3

Just for point of reference for folks that are not down with C++; my question has two examples in it. The first one uses [`enable_if_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) which is from C++14 and the second uses [`apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) which requires C++17. The user changed my [[Recursion]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion) tag to a [[C++11]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2642059+[c%2b%2b11]) tag.

At best the question was related to C++17, not C++11. (Even the users answer used [`make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) which is from C++14.) The only reason that I could come up with for adding the [[C++11]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2642059+[c%2b%2b11]) tag was an attempt to earn the [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) badge.

I obviously rolled this change back. But What I'd like to hear is that rolled back changes don't count toward "Edit and Answer" badges, so as not to encourage behavior like this. Is that the case?

Comment: Earning a badge isn't a very good motivation. He could have done that by adding a [c++14] tag, or even a [c++17] tag (he has the requisite reputation to create tags). As you said, his own answer uses C++14 features. This was probably just a mistake.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that tag only edits count toward the Refiner badge anyways.  At least they haven't for me - only the ones where I have edited the post content seem to count.  That user is close to a gold C++11 badge, and needs more votes on that tag, however.

Comment: @Matthew And the other shoe drops. I'm sure you're right. I would still like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: In general, it's best not to assume malicious intents. I think @CodyGray's explanation is still the best one. A 20k+ user doesn't need to make bad edits to get more rep in a tag; they just need to watch that tag for questions to answer. Also, this isn't a [meta-tag:feature-request]; it's a question about existing functionality. I'm retagging the question. (...Feels ironic somehow.) It could *become* a feature request, but it isn't right now.

Comment: @jpmc26 As long as you're not trying to get badges by retagging...

Comment: @JonathanMee odds are Piotr decided "I need a few more votes in C++11.  So I'll go through the questions I have answered and say 'is this a C++11 question?  Yep?  Ok, edit it in'".  The problem here is more "bad edit" more than anything: a C++17 or C++14 tag would be more appropriate, and your question is not *really* about recursion (insofar as it is about avoiding recursion overhead).

Comment: Not long ago I found someone who had defaced his own question (destroying all content and replacing it with a bland non-question). After a rollback he rolled back *that* in turn - and got a badge for it. \*sigh*

Comment: The user in question has made 10 tag revisions since the beginning of the month, 4 of which added [tag:C++11]. I have a suspicion that @Yakk is _kind of_ right, but that mistags are accidental rather than nefarious.

Comment: @JonathanMee The next gold badge objective of this user is the [tag:c++11] Gold. It may be healthy to assume he's doing that just to get there faster...

Answer (score 2):

It was "no" in [the original proposal for the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/340456):

> Let's say that you answer something, and:
>
> - You edit the question 12 hours before or after answering it. This allows you to edit now, answer later—or answer now and edit later, when you have the time.
> - **Your edit isn't rolled back, or outright rejected if it was a suggested edit**
> - The question is not closed for any reason, even simply being a duplicate
> - Your answer has a score of 1 or higher

but it didn't make it to [the actual badge requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239913/340456), I assume because of the difficulty to implement.

The short answer is, yes.